# Calculating number of combinations of a character reference with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

If I have a $6$ character reference field which can be made up with a combination of numbers and letters $(0-9 \space \text{and} \space$ A-Z), then I can work out how many possible combinations there are by taking the number of character options $(36)$ and then times it each time by the number of available character spaces. So for $6$, it would be calculated as $36^6 = 2,176,782,336.$

My problem with this is that it can create bad reference codes such as $000000$ or ZZZZZZ. I, therefore, want to stipulate that while the repetition of a character is allowed, the same character cannot be used next to each other. I.e. ABABAB is acceptable but AABBAA is not.

Please help me to understand how I can calculate this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Choose the first character.  You have how many choices?  Now.... *choose the second character*.  Note that the second character can not be the same as the first character and so there is one fewer option available.  Do the same thing for the third character noting that it can't be the same choice as the second character.  Continue in this fashion and finish by applying the rule of product and multiplying the number of options for each step together into a final answer.

Comment: To emphasize... having the final results for things known like $k^n$ or $n!$ or such is all well and good... but you need to remember your fundamentals.  Those formulas and more are derived from the basics of the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) or [rule of sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum) and other fundamental counting principles.

Answer (score 1):

We know that first digit can be any of these $36$ characters . Lets say that we wrote $\color{red}{c}$ as the first digit.Moreover ,  we want that there is not $\color{red}{cc}$ , so the second digits cannot be $\color{red}{c}$ , we  now have $35$ choices to select . Let assume that we wrote $\color{blue}{b}$ as the second digits , so we cannot write $\color{blue}{b}$ as the third digits , but we can use $c$ in third digits , so we have $35$ choices to select again. This goes to like that.

As a result $36$ choices for the first and $35$ for the rest , then if we have lenght $n$ digits then the answer is $$36 \times 35^{n-1}$$

In your case , $$36 \times 35 ^5$$